# Can an c++ compiled DLL differ in code without size difference?

Tags: c++, dll

I use to get vendor parts of my software delivered, they are closed-source and compiled in DLLs, I normally compare File properties in bytes (actual file size) with previous ones.

If i hash the files they will always differ due to an version header, can you answer;
can I rely on taking conclusions such as the source inside the DLLs is the same, once the size in bytes show to be matching for both?

Or is there a better method to check if something has changed? I'm talking about net modules that get regularly updated, sometimes the size changes and I can certainly say an fix has been done on it's source, hence why the final compiled DLLs differ in size, but does a trivial commit onto the source also translate in size difference that Windows can recognize in properties, when looking at the compiled DLLs?

The goal is to know if something has changed in newer versions, while the vendor DLLs are closedsource and they do not provide source.

I would like to clarify the question some more: If the files doesn't differ in size (bytes), is it possible that code has been added? (because changing/replacing the same code characters with the exact same amount would make the same final size) or, if the source contains more characters, will it definately translate to size?

Comment: Why couldn't they?  Add a few instructions, remove a few, for example.   I wouldn't rely on the size.

Comment: I know relying on it isn't recommended, the question is better said: Can source differ, when the size in bytes is still the same?

Comment: @Snps, Yeah but it's part of a bigger package, if the main incremements revision (OS) then these modules take the same revision with them, and if changed, pack the changes, if unchanged, wouldn't, but still will have the latest headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PE files have a specified *file alignment*, to which they are padded out with zeros. This means  DLL is always some multiple of that size. This makes it much more likely that similar, but different DLLs will be the same size on disk.

It should be obvious, too simply  that changing an internal constant from a 4 to a 5 would not change the file size, but could have a profound impact on how the code runs.

Your best bet is to generate a *hash* like MD5 or SHA1 of files, and compare their hashes.

In addition to what Lightness said, there *are* some tools that will try to compare executable files at the *section* level, with the goal of determining that two files have the same *code*, despite differences in Metadata. However, they're definitely considered reverse engineering tools, and might be difficult to use. To get very far down this road, you're going to require a firm understanding of the PE file structure, and probably some x86 assembly as well.

It'd be far easier to ask the upstream vendor. Even closed-source software can have thorough changelogs.

Comment: Thanks, but as the meta version header is also found internal, hashing would also gives different hashes when it's the same except for that.

Answer (score 4):

Comparing binaries by file size alone is ridiculous. You can trivially produce two entirely different programs that have the same file size. You should compare files byte-wise, not size-wise.

That said, the only reliable way to tell whether a program's semantics have been changed — be it through a bug fix or new feature — is to read the product's changelog, or examine its source code.